# type-punned pointer challenge

Tags: c++, pointers, type-punning

so I've got a little challenge with the RF24Network library from here: https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24Network

I've modified the library and am currently trying to get it running on a Teensy 3.5 which is ARM and 32 bit instead of AVR 8 bit which I was using until now.

This:

```
RF24NetworkHeader *header = (RF24NetworkHeader*)(&frame_buffer);
```

to my understanding is illegal but works on Atmegas (328p/2560). On Teensy, this crashes in my modified Version of the library (I suppose because I changed the size of RF24NetworkHeader struct).

in the following lines of code I read and manipulate the Header (and therefore the frame_buffer, as "header" is a pointer to frame_buffer). and then, Frame_buffer is being reused as it is a global variable.

i first created a new `RF24NetworkHeader` object and memcopied the Contents of Frame_buffer there and then created a new pointer:

```
RF24NetworkHeader hdr;
memcpy(&hdr, frame_buffer, sizeof(RF24NetworkHeader));
RF24NetworkHeader *header;
header = &hdr;
```

however I forgot to copy Header back to Frame_buffer as the Contents of Frame_buffer are further processed in other functions.

`RF24NetworkHeader` is a struct consisting of `uint16_t`'s, `unsigned chars` and one `unsigned char` array of fixed size.

Is there a way to properly access frame_buffer as if it was a `RF24NetworkHeader` without violating strict aliasing rules?
I read that the Union approach for C++ will work most of the time but is illegal too.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to decide if you are programmig in C or C++. The rules are quite different. For C a `union` that covers all the types that you are interested in is the right choice.

Comment: it is C++, what would be the best approach there?

thanks